# Can not reference element in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am working in an AngularJS controller, trying to get the current month's name, this is my code:

```
$scope.months = {};
        $scope.currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
        $http.get("json/months.json").success(function (data) {
            $scope.months = data;
        });
        console.log($scope.months);
        $scope.currentMonthName = $scope.months[0].name;
//Rest of file
```

This is my JSON file:

```
[
    {"id": "0", "name": "January" },
    {"id": "1", "name": "February"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "March"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "April"},
    {"id": "4", "name": "May"},
    {"id": "5", "name": "June"},
    {"id": "6", "name": "July"},
    {"id": "7", "name": "August"},
    {"id": "8", "name": "September"},
    {"id": "9", "name": "October"},
    {"id": "10", "name": "November"},
    {"id": "11", "name": "December"}
]
```

However my $scope.currentMonth is throwing an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'. What I make of this is that he did not even retrieve the JSON file correctly (undefined), however after logging this file to console I can see that he did retrieve it correctly, which leaves me to wonder what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$http` query is asynchronous.

So try this (you need to set the assignment in the query callback) :

```
$scope.months = {};
$scope.currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
$http.get("json/months.json").success(function (data) {
   $scope.months = data;
   console.log($scope.months);
   $scope.currentMonthName = $scope.months[0].name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to parse it before you use it.

```
$http.get("json/months.json").success(function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $scope.months = data;
});
```

JSON is just a string. Use `JSON.parse("json")` to convert it to an actual object.

Comment: I thought $http.get did that for you?

Comment: I don't know AngularJs, but most probably it will not do that for you.

Comment: I just used the below answer without explicitly parsing the JSON, so I guess it does :P